# Stackdriver logging of stdout/stderr suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine

I have NodeJS 10 based Standard code hosted on `google-app-engine`. Until last update, `stdout` and `stderr` logs were being imported automatically to the stackdriver logging. However after last deployment, the `stdout`/`stderr` completely stopped appearing in stackdriver. I tried to migrate traffic to the earlier known version but the logs still won't appear. The service appears to be working without any issues, just the logging functionality is gone. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, **there is nothing wrong with your service versioning**, the **logging functionality for stdout and stderr is deprecated** and **no longer write any logs to Stackdriver.** Instead, you can use **the Stackdriver Logging API**.

Here's a step-by-step guide to configure the **[Stackdriver Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for Node.js** that you can follow, and you should be good to go.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I don't think it is deprecated as I couldn't find it in any of the change-logs. However, the stdout logging started on its own this morning.

Comment: To clarify my response, I did not mean stdout and stderr are deprecated themselves but the way you are implementing the writing to Stackdriver Logging. More info about [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/release-notes#March_15_2019)

Still, i would highly recommend to use this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) for Stackdriver Logging API using Node.js if the problem persists. Cheers!